# MPMoviePlayerController cannot play some 3gp format video

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, avfoundation, avplayer

I use MPMoviePlayerViewController to play a video with format 3gp. some video can played,but others cannot be played. MPMoviePlayerViewController will loading and end immediately,just like the video is 0 second duration.
i thought there must be sty wrong with the video. but i use the iphone's video player inside the album, it can play the video!
So i think maybe MPMoviePlayerViewController is not powerful.and i wanna try to use avfoundation framework avplayer to play video. add a sublayer into my content view. failed..
that drive me crazy! does anyone met the some problem?

here is my code

```
-(void) playMovieWithSDK: (NSURL*) movieUrl
{
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 3.2) {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mSdk4Player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
    mSdk4Player.navigationController.navigationBar.tag = 1000;
    if (mSdk4Player) {
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mSdk4Player];
        mSdk4Player.moviePlayer.scalingMode= MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
        mSdk4Player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        mSdk4Player.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [mSdk4Player release];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver: self
                                                selector: @selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                    name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object: mSdk4Player.moviePlayer];
    }
}
else if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] < 3.2) { // sdk 3.0 播放器
    MPMoviePlayerController* mSdk3player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieUrl];
    mSdk3player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver: self
                                            selector: @selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object: mSdk3player];
    [mSdk3player play];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video you are trying to play might not be compatible with the basic Codecs supported by MPMoviePlayerController.

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW20):

This class plays any movie or audio file supported in iOS. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:

- H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps.
  (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
- MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)

If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i had found the problem. the audio track format is AMR not AAC.